# Modulus in Pascal

Tags: c++, pascal, modulus

I am trying to translate some Pascal code into C++ code. I am stuck trying to figure out how to translate this portion.

```
Function ThetaG_JD(jd : double) : double;
var
UT,TU,GMST : double;
begin
**UT   := Frac(jd + 0.5);**
jd   := jd - UT;
TU   := (jd - 2451545.0)/36525;
GMST := 24110.54841 + TU * (8640184.812866 + TU * (0.093104 - TU * 6.2E-6));
**GMST := Modulus(GMST + 86400.0*1.00273790934*UT,86400.0);**
ThetaG_JD := twopi * GMST/86400.0;
end; {Function ThetaG_JD}
```

I am particularly having trouble with the two lines I made bold. How can I translate this to c++? Thank you so much.

Comment: That appears to be a function call as modulus in Pascal is the `MOD` operator. Do you have the source of the Modulus function?

Comment: I unfortunately do not have the source. I can't figure out why the author wrote out modulus and didn't just use mod. But even if he did, these aren't integers so I don't think mod is appropriate?

Comment: You could assume it's a floating-point variant of `mod`, which would translate as `fmod()`, but don't quote me ;-) Similarly `Frac()` is probably returning just the fractional portion, but really it's anybody's guess. If you don't have all the source code you can't actually do the job properly.

Comment: The code you've posted calls a `modulus` function, which you have not included in your question. As it is not standard Pascal function (the `mod` operator does the modulus operation in Pascal) and as we have no idea what the `modulus` function does or attempts to do, it's impossible for us to explain why it's not working as you expect. Find the source (or at least the documenation) for the modulus function and we can possibly help. Without that info, you're probably going to have to just debug this yourself, as we don't have the ability to do so.

Answer (score 0):

In C++ the equivalent functions would be:

`fmod` to get a floating point modulus

`modf` to break a floating point item into its fraction and integral parts (equivalent of `Frac`).

Comment: I am trying to understand modf at the moment. Would one replace that line with something such as 'ut = modf(jd + .5, &fracPart);' ?

Comment: Almost, the second parameter is the integer part, so you should name your dummy variable `intPart`. `ut = modf(jd + 0.5, &intPart);`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to calculate **Julian Day**, **Greenwich Mean Sidereal Time** and **Local Mean Sidereal Time**, maybe the below can help you - written in **PowerShell**:

```
<#
    .Synopsis
    Astronomy calculations

    .Description
    Some helper functions to calculate:
    - Julian Day,
    - Greenwich Mean Sidereal time,
    - Local Mean Sidereal Time.
#>
cls

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julian_day#Julian_day_number_calculation
function Get-JulianDay
{
    param ( [System.DateTime]$dt )
    $year = $dt.Year
    $month = $dt.Month
    $day = $dt.Day
    $hour = $dt.Hour
    $minute = $dt.Minute
    $second = $dt.Second
    $a = [System.Math]::Floor((14 - $month) / 12)
    $y = $year + 4800 - $a
    $m = $month + 12 * $a - 3
    $JDN = $day + [System.Math]::Floor((153 * $m + 2) / 5) + 365 * $y + [System.Math]::Floor($y / 4) - [System.Math]::Floor($y / 100) + [System.Math]::Floor($y / 400) - 32045
    $JD = $JDN + ($hour - 12) / 24 + $minute / 1440 + $second / 86400
    return ($JD)
}

# https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidereal_time#Definition
# http://aa.usno.navy.mil/faq/docs/GAST.php
function Get-GMST
{
    param ( [double]$JD )
    $D = $JD - 2451545.0
    $GMST = 18.697374558 + 24.06570982441908 * $D
    return ($GMST % 24)
}

function Get-LMST
{
    param ( [double]$gmst, [double]$longitude )
    return ( $gmst + $longitude / 15.0 )
}

# Test above functions
$current = (Get-Date).ToUniversalTime()
$jd = Get-JulianDay -dt $current
$gmst = Get-GMST -JD $jd
$longitude = 17.668487800
$lmst = Get-LMST -gmst $gmst -longitude $longitude
$lst = [timespan]::FromHours($lmst).ToString()
Write-Host "Local mean sidereal time: $lst"
```